# Hookin CreateProcessEx

Tags: windows, winapi

i would like to systemwide hook `CreateProcessEx` 
it is redirects all windows calls into my wrapper function
where I will log names to textfile then  call oruginal `CreateProcessEx`

Can it be easy and safely done ?

I would like hook all systemwide calls  to it but not etternaly 
for some period of time only.. How to do it?

If I will find the adress of this api call in ram then overvrite 
it with call to my procedure, how then I will call the oryginal 
function if there it is somewhat corrupted?

Answer (score 4):

Hooking `CreateProcess` is the wrong approach for a few reasons. There is an approved mechanism for doing this sort of thing but you need a driver to be loaded. Your driver can then simply leverage the [`PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

With that said, would your needs not be served by using the auditing functionality built into Windows? Turning on process creation auditing will cause the system to write an event log entry whenever a process is created, detailing plenty of information about the process being started, including the image path.

Answer (score 1):

`CreateProcessEx()` is a user-mode function.  You have to patch it on a per-process basis.  That means creating a DLL that is injected into every running process, such as by using `SetWindowsHookEx()` or the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs` Registry key, and then have that DLL patch the PE Imports table of every process it is loaded into.

Comment: +1 for respect, but your hints are totally wrong: AppInit_DLLs is used only for apps linked to user32.dll!!! SetWindowsHookEx is per-desktop basics. So if I create console process in another desktop your hints do nothing.